# Mixing spring 3 and 4

Tags: spring

I have a legacy application that uses Spring 3.x. It's built using Maven and creates a war file. It's big, perhaps what would be called a monolith nowadays.

I'm slowly moving to a micro services architecture and as a first stage I'd like to create Maven sub-projects built as JAR files (within the web application) that contain Spring controllers that use the newer @RestController annotations of Spring 4.

Will there likely be problems do you think of mixing version 3 and 4 of Spring? I'd like to scan the package structure of the jar file from the existing Spring 3 app in order to detect the Spring 4 annotations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mix version of a framework (be it spring or hibernate) it will bite you.

Comment: Tony - good question, but are you asking "will there be problems mixing XML with annotations?".  Have you tried to upgrade the legacy to Spring 4, and are having compatibility issues?  Spring supports mixing both an annotation approach with XML (i.e. phase out XML slowly towards an annotation approach).

Comment: Spring 3.x is "legacy" now? Either way, there's a clear migration path and most of the stuff should be backwards-compatible anyway. Mixing 3 and 4 makes no sense, simply upgrade to 4.x and fix whatever's broken.